# function performs differently when calling it via onValueChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native component that allows me to fire a function called `updateTags` when it is pressed.

```
<Checkbox
    style={styles.checkbox}
    value={item.isChecked}
    onValueChange={() => updateTags(item.id)}
/>
```

The function essentially updates an object list to reflect just the checkboxes that have been toggled to active or inactive. I've no problem when utilizing the function in this way.

The problem is that users will revisit a settings page and need their prior choices pre-selected. To do that, I run this

```
const setPriorTags = () => {
    data.tags.map((item, index) => {
        updateTags(item.id);
    });
}
```

When the screen comes into focus, I run the `setPriorTags()` function, the nested `updateTags()` function behaves differently compared to when I initialized it from `onValueChange()` as shown above. The problem is that it updates my object list in a manner as if only one prior selection was saved, even if I have more than one. Why is the same function behaving differently, and how can I fix this?

For reference:

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState(SelectionOption.dietTags);

const updateTags = (id) => {
// Note: this function works as intended when I have a list of multiple checkboxes
    let temp = tags.map((tag) => {
        if (id === tag.id) {
            return { ...tag, isChecked: !tag.isChecked };
        }
        return tag;
    });

    setTags(temp);
}
```

My data object for the list of all items

```
export const dietTags = [
    {id: 1, label: "Vegan", isChecked: false},
    {id: 2, label: "Vegetarian", isChecked: false},
    {id: 3, label: "Pescatarian", isChecked: false},
    {id: 4, label: "Carnivore", isChecked: false}
]
```

the list of pre-selected items gets stored in `data` from an outside data source (Firebase). Example output of `data.tags`:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "isChecked": true, "label": "Vegan"},
    {"id": 3, "isChecked": true, "label": "Pescatarian"}
]
```

The desired output after running `setPriorTags()` is this:

```
[
    {id: 1, label: "Vegan", isChecked: true},
    {id: 2, label: "Vegetarian", isChecked: false},
    {id: 3, label: "Pescatarian", isChecked: true},
    {id: 4, label: "Carnivore", isChecked: false}
]
```

Right now, the output of the function within `.map()` looks like this (because Pescatarian was the last item in the list):

```
[
    {id: 1, label: "Vegan", isChecked: false},
    {id: 2, label: "Vegetarian", isChecked: false},
    {id: 3, label: "Pescatarian", isChecked: true},
    {id: 4, label: "Carnivore", isChecked: false}
]
```

Comment: When you call `setPriorTags`, where does `data` come from? Are you sure it has the correct values?

Comment: Also, two notes, use `forEach` when you don't need to return anything; `map` is for returning a modified version of the input array. And when you are using an array with IDs like this, prefer using an object with the IDs as keys. Then you don't need to check each value to see if it's the one you want to change. On large lists this saves a lot of time

Comment: After you set the tags in state, do you persist them outside the component? State will be wiped out when the screen pops off of the navigation stack. If you want to persist it out has to be stored somewhere else. I think this is likely to be the issue

Comment: @Abe I've tried `forEach` and the outcome is the same. I updated my question to provide more context about the data. It's coming from firebase.

Comment: Changing to forEach won't change the output - it just helps whoever reads your code to know what you intended to do. So if the data comes from Firebase, where do you update the Firebase data after the user makes changes to the checkbox?

Comment: @Abe I'm temporarily storing it in `tags` until the user presses a confirmation button to initiate a separate function for updating the database. I filter out the items marked `isChecked: true` for saving.

Comment: Ok, say you navigate to the settings page, and several items come back from Firebase as checked. Does that show up? You can test this with local data instead of Firebase to check this.

Comment: @Abe I've added more details to the question that should provide more clarity. Let me know if that helps

Comment: I think the issue is a typo. Your code reads `return { ...tag, isChecked: !tag.isChecked };`, but you want to return `isChecked: tag.isChecked`. I.e. you are returning the opposite

Comment: @Abe hmm now I don't get anything back. I think it makes sense to use the `!` because we're looking for instances where the default state: `false` is the opposite of what is stored in the database: `true`